# Heap Sort C doesn't work when change from array to array unsigned int

Tags: c, int, unsigned, heapsort

My code works properly when all variables and array are defined as int, but if I change the type to unsigned int, it won't work.
Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void swap(unsigned int *a, unsigned int *b){
unsigned int temp;
    temp=*a ; *a=*b ; *b=temp;
}
void heapify(unsigned int A[], unsigned int i, unsigned int n){ 
//sort from root i

    unsigned int L = 2*i+1; 
// node left child
    unsigned int R = 2*i+2; 
//node  right child
    unsigned int max = i; 
//set max node is root
    if(L < n && A[L] > A[max]) max = L; 
//if node child > max, set that node is max
    if(R < n && A[R] > A[max]) max = R; 
    if(max != i) {
        swap(&A[i], &A[max]);
        heapify(A, max, n);//recursive tree with root is node swaped
        }

}

void buildHeap(unsigned int A[], unsigned int n){

    unsigned int i = n/2 - 1;
    for(; i >= 0; i--) heapify(A, i, n);
    }

void heapSort(unsigned int A[], unsigned int n){

    buildHeap(A, n);
    unsigned int i = n-1;
    for(; i >= 0; i--){
        swap(&A[0], &A[i]);
        heapify(A, 0, i);
}
}

void PrintArray(unsigned int A[], unsigned int n){
    unsigned int i;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("%d ", A[i]);
    }
}
int main(){
    unsigned int A[]={1,6,8,9,7,1,65,92,2,9,2,5,73,9,1,5};
    unsigned int n=sizeof (A)/sizeof(unsigned int);
    PrintArray(A,n);
    heapSort(A,n);
    PrintArray(A,n);
}
```

The output is stuck at print the old array and nothing happens after that.

What should I do?

Comment: When `i` is unsigned, `i` is always `>= 0`. The compiler should have warned you about that. If not, try compiling with `-Wall`. And always fix every warning that the compiler gives you.

Comment: Tks guy, you save my life.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is at `buildHeap` - you set your iterator as `unsigned int`, and run a loop until `i` is no longer positive - which in the cash of `unsigned int` will never happen.

```
void buildHeap(unsigned int A[], unsigned int n){

    unsigned int i = n/2 - 1;
    for(; i >= 0; i--) heapify(A, i, n);
    }
```

Comment: Tks, I understand now.

Comment: `0` is not a positive integer. The code clearly writes `>= 0`, which indeed cannot become false. @NguyễnQuốcKhánh Enable compiler warnings. Any modern compiler will warn about such flaws ("condition cannot become false" or similar). If your's doesn't, get a better compiler (e.g. gcc, clang).